# ORA-01722: invalid number in column with numbers only?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I did a rather easy view to return only rows where there is number is CONTRACT_ID column. CONTRACT_ID has data type number(8).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cid AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM transactions
  WHERE contract_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND LENGTH(contract_id) > 0;
```

View works just fine until I scroll down to row ~2950 where I get ORA-01722. Same thing happens if I want to export data to Excel, my file gets only ~2950 rows instead of expected ~20k.
Any idea what might be causing this and how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: `length()` expects a character value, and makes no sense on a number. What exactly are you trying to do with that? `contract_id is not null` already removes anything that does not contain any value.

Comment: @Lostinsql . . . I could imagine this happening if `transactions` were a view.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to see only rows where contract_id is not empty or null.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff transactions are actually a table, not a view.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "empty number". It either contains a value or it is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote too much SQL.. The following will provide all the results you require:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cid AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM transactions
  WHERE contract_id IS NOT NULL
```

You can't `LENGTH()` a number - a number is either null or it's a value, so you don't need this kind of check.

Passing a number to `LENGTH()` will turn it into a string first, i.e. `LENGTH(TO_CHAR(numbercolumn))`. You don't even need a `LENGTH()` check for null strings, as to oracle NULL string and a zero length string are equivalent, and calling `LENGTH()` on an empty string or a null, will return null, not 0 (so `LENGTH(myNullStr) = 0` doesnt work out; it's not comparing 0 = 0, it's comparing null = 0 and null compared with anything is always false).

The only time this seems to cause confusion is when the string columns in the table are CHAR types rather than VARCHAR types, and people forget that assigning an empty string to a CHAR causes it to become space padded out to the CHAR length hence, not a zero length string any more

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove redundant condition about length(), it's senseless. I'm not sure how it can produce such error, but check whether error disappered after it.

If no, replace star (`*`) to some field names, say, contract_id. If it will fix error - it would appoint that error source somewhere into removed fields (say, if generated column used).

I cannot imagine how error can be still alive after that, by if so, I'd tried to move it into other tablespace and add into fields list a call of logging function which stores rowid's of rows read - thus check which row produces error.